# How to cipher a string with info from a txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So this is a code I have for a cipher program:

```
cipher = {}
for f in open('mapping.txt'):
  org, cip = f.split()
  cipher[ord(org)] = cip


inpt = input('Enter string: ')

inpt.translate(cipher)
print(inpt)
```

Doesn't work, but the text file is this:

```
a e
e i
i o
o u
u a
```

So what I want to do is swap the vowel with the one next to it? I *think* i'm on the right track, but i'm not sure, can some one show me a better way to do so? And the letters in the text file don't have to be vowels, they can be anything at all, but this is just for testing, thanks in advance :)

Comment: This can be done with `str.translate` too. `str.replace` will return an incorrect answer in some cases.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Where will `str.replace` fail?

Comment: `inpt = inpt.translate(cipher[org], cipher[cip] )` this gives me an error, can you please show me how this would work?

Comment: @samir What do you need `cipher_` for?

Comment: i don't know, i was just testing different ways, i'm not sure really :/ i don't think i do

Comment: @thefourtheye text = "aaaeee", according to the cipher the answer should be `'eeeiii'`. But, `text = text.replace('a','e');text.replace('e','i')
` will return :`'iiiiii'`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Oh yes. `translate` doesnt need looping? Hitting python reference now.

Comment: can you please implement the correct method into my code as an answer?

Comment: @samir Try replacing `cipher[org] = cip` with `cipher[ord(org)] = cip`, and then apply: `inpt.translate(cipher)`. **Read the docs properly**.

Comment: I did that and nothing changed, i updated my code

Comment: I'm an idiot! I didn't store `inpt.trans` in a variable! thank you @AshwiniChaudhary !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cipher = {}
for f in open('mapping.txt'):
  org, cip = f.split()
  cipher[ord(org)] = cip


inpt = input('Enter string: ')

inpt = inpt.translate(cipher)
print('Message: ' + inpt)
```

Thanks to @AshwiniChaudhary!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from string import maketrans

input_cipher = open('mapping.txt', 'r').read()
intab = ''.join(el[0] for el in input_cipher.split())
outtab = ''.join(el[1] for el in input_cipher.split())
trantab = maketrans(intab, outtab)

inpt = input('Enter string: ')

inpt = inpt.translate(trantab)
print(inpt)
```

Comment: And OP will get: `ImportError: cannot import name maketrans`