# replacing values from file python

Tags: python, python-3.x

if a file contains A 2 B 3 ,  have to replace the user input if it contains an A or B with the values 2 and 3, (Example: A banana should turn to 2 banana) so far i have done like this:

```
word=input("Enter string: ")
word=list(word)
with open('mapping.txt') as f:
 key = {}
  for line in f:
   first, second = line.split()
   key[first] = second
    for i in word:
     if first in i:
      word=word.replace(i,key[i])
```

but it does not change even does nott even prints, would u kindly Help Me

Comment: Can you fix your indentation? It's hard to know how your code is running when we can't tell what's nested within what.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18571730/846892

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
word=input("Enter string: ")
with open('input.txt') as f:
  key = {}
  for line in f:
    first, second = line.split()
    key[first] = second
for replacement in key:
    word=word.replace(replacement,key[replacement])

print(word)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571730/how-to-cipher-a-string-with-info-from-a-txt-file#comment27326085_18571730

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary the question you quote has no accepted answer. The reasons you give for using translate don't hold, since there is no hint that Hasnain is trying to do more than replacing letters with numbers, so there I don't see any case that replace won't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because each time you read the `mapping.txt` file, you create your dictionary, and at the same time you are checking the replacement words. So the first line from mapping will create one item in the dictionary, and then you check that one item against the string.

You also don't print anything.

You need to create your mapping once and then check the entire dictionary, like this:

```
mapping = {}
with open('mapping.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        word, replacement = line.split()
        mapping[word.strip()] = replacement.strip()

user_input = input("Enter string: ")

new_line = ' '.join(mapping.get(word, word) for word in user_input.split())

print(new_line)
```

When you run that, here is what you'll get:

```
Enter string: this is A string with a B
this is 2 string with a 3
```